# Template use without angle brackets - Overloading?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I'm a little confused about the idea of using `template` with `<>` brackets and without them. When I compiled the code I got the output I wasn't expecting, and didn't figure out why.

For example, let's say I have 2 functions and a `template` with the same prototype:

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T> void copy(T a, T b)
{
    cout << "template copy" << endl;
}
void copy(int a, int b)
{
    cout << "int copy" << endl;
}
void copy(string a, string b)
{
    cout << "string copy" << endl;
}
```

And after compiling the main function:

```
int main()
{
    copy<int>(1, 2);
    copy<string>("ha", "ha");
    copy("ab", "bc");
    copy(1, 2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

the output looked like this:

```
template copy
template copy
template copy
int copy
```

for the record all the code is written on the same CPP file.

Comment: Your code is bad... See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and think about [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: The compiler will select the function with the best/most explicitly matching signature first. So for strings and ints it will select the non-template versions first. In your case for string (number 3) it will select a template for char array.

Comment: Third call to `copy` is using `copy<const char*>`

Comment: For the one saying my code is bad, this is a simple fast code I made on an online compiler to try understanding the problem of this post, when I code I don't use std, I know it's a bad habbit :)

Comment: if you need to make excuses, it isnt simple code ;)

Comment: Rookie mistake... Thank you @Zereges :)

Comment: It ain't no excuse buddy, I literally don't use std, the online compiler adds it. @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: `Overloading?`: yes. `copy("ab", "bc")` will have a perfect instantiation of the template for `T` equals `const char*`, whereas it would need an implicit conversion to `std::string` if using the function: https://godbolt.org/z/PjMeY5691

Comment: Note that `void copy(int, int)` isn't a specialization of `template <typename T>void copy(T, T)`.

Comment: *"I got the output I wasn't expecting"*. which is your expectation?

Comment: @PKramer I tried it with `std::cout << typeid(T).name()` which prints `char const * __ptr64` in msvc.

Comment: @Zereges Good test :) I stand corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember that literal strings are really (constant) arrays of characters, which decays to (constant) pointers to `char`, i.e. `const char*`.

Since your function taking `std::string` arguments is not a direct match, and the compiler will not do a conversion, the template overload will be used (as `copy<const char*>`).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if you add "using namespace std::string_literals", you can specify a string literal by adding "s", e.g. "ab"s, or "bc"s. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Answer (score 1):

In these calls

```
copy<int>(1, 2);
copy<string>("ha", "ha");
```

you explicitly specified the template argument. So the compiler will consider only template functions.

In this call

```
copy("ab", "bc");
```

you did not specify the template argument. So the compiler will consider all overloaded functions with the name `copy` and select the most viable function.

The type of arguments that represent string literals is `const char [3]`.

Due to the standard conversion sequence the arguments are explicitly converted to pointers to first characters of the string literals of the type `const char *`.

So the compiler can deduce the type of the template argument as the type `const char *`.

To call the non-template function

```
void copy(string a, string b)
{
    cout << "string copy" << endl;
}
```

the compiler needs to use one more conversion (user-defined conversion) to convert the pointers to objects of the type `std::string`.

So as the template function requires less conversions then it is considered by the compiler as more suitable. And as a result you get the output

```
template copy
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void f( T , T )
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<T, const char *>::value << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    f( "ab", "bc" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```